# Android ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH intent never finishes after long speech

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I started intent and wait for the result. It works pretty well on short speech but it does not give me the answer of the speech if it is too long. (nearly 1 min)

```
final Intent searchIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

    searchIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "tr");
    searchIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, true);
    searchIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, true);

    startActivityForResult(searchIntent, VOICE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Is there a way other than SpeechRecognizer to get results from ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH intent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working solution:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, yourPackageHere);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1000);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Your Prompt");
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

But before use this feature you should check if user granted the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission and device has `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` available.

Recognise Speech has an interesting behaviour with long speech. If you give a small number to `MAX_RESULTS` recognise speech screen freezes after a long speech. So you need to keep number bigger and you get a result in `onActivityResult` with `List<String> results` from recognise speech intent. You can get results with a loop and than use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this google text to speech intent launcher,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak Now");
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, REQUEST_CODE);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT =1000 ;
    //views from activity
    TextView mTextTv;
    ImageButton mVoiceBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

        mTextTv= findViewById( R.id.textTv );
        mVoiceBtn=findViewById( R.id.voiceBtn );

        //button clic to show speech to text dilog
        mVoiceBtn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                speak();
            }
        } );
    }

    private void speak() {
        //intent is show speech to text dialog
        Intent intent= new Intent( RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH );
        intent.putExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault() );
        intent.putExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "HI speak something" );

        // Start intent
        try {
            //in there was no errror
            //show dilog
            startActivityForResult( intent, REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            //show messageof error and show
            Toast.makeText( this,""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }
    //recive voice input and handle it

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );

        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT:{
                if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && null!=data){
                    //get text arry form voice intent
                    ArrayList<String> result=data.getStringArrayListExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS );
                    //set to text view
                    mTextTv.setText( result.get( 0 ) );
                }
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.